# why we need storage allocation in compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I know storage allocation is mapping of the data code into appropriate location in main memory.
But why seperate portion for different data for example stack data in java is stored in classInformation area,dynamic(object) data in heap,String data in ConstantPool(via literal when we make),Function in method area etc
So Is the need for storage allocation is only to provide Ease of access as well as making our code cleaner while storing in mainmemory?

Answer (score 2):

First of all your question should have been - *Why do we need different storage areas in the JVM?*.

There are 5 different Storage areas in each executing (instance of) JVM.

```
Shared among all threads running in a JVM instance
Method Area  --> Contains information about classes loaded by the JVM.
Heap  --> common area for allocation of memory. Even String pool is part of this space.

Separate for each Thread
Java Stacks  --> Contains state of Java (not native level) level methods 
PC registers -> Program counter to keep track of Java method execution.
Native Method Stacks --> Stack for keeping track / state of native calls (methods).
```

More information [here](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html)

Comment: No my question is specific to compiler only(Somewhat it related to jvm specific storage[infact every programming language needs storage allocation]).I know a little about where the data resides in java so i mentioned here.

Comment: @Jack - Then please *elaborate / clarify* your question

Comment: when Compiler compiles our code it loads our code in main memory and then stores various data of our program in seperate memory area of our main memoryRight?So why Compilers needs to store that data in seperate areas.Are the 2 reasons sufficient easy access to the code and Seperate Portions  for cleaner efficient Code

Comment: @Jack - No. It *creates code* to put variables in appropriate memory areas. Foe example it will have an instruction `bipush` to push an int value as a byte onto the stack.  or `aload`,`astore` etc. You can check the opcodes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings). The JVM will understand where to put what based on the byte code.

Comment: okay not a standard for every programming language.But the Answer to this question still remains why compiler need seperate areas to put variables in appropriate memory areas.